# ucontext and thread local storage

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, pthreads, thread-local-storage

The platform I am asking about is linux.  Thread local storage I am talking about is `pthread_xxx` or `__thread` in gcc.

I want to use ucontext stuff, i.e., makecontext, swapcontext, etc. in my program.  So my question is, how does it work with thread local storage?  More specifically, if I switch to another fiber using swapcontext or setcontext, does the thread local storage change as well, or is thread local storage not a part of context?

Another question: if TLS will be changed by `setcontext`/`swapcontext`, then is there anything that will stick to thread, no matter how I change the context?  On the other hand, if TLS will stick to context, then is there anything that will stick to thread and is not changed by setcontext/swapcontext?

According to [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_%28computer_science%29), the Windows platform does have thread-local storage and fiber-local storage.

Answer (score 2):

It's not well specified how thread local storage interacts with setcontext/swapcontext.

On Linux, thread local storage is not affected by setcontext/swapcontext and some software relies on that behaviour - see a recent discussion on the netbsd mailing list for further insights: [swapcontext() around pthreads](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.netbsd.devel.kernel/42682)

Also related are some thoughts about the interaction of TLS with parallelism in C++: [TLS_and_Parallelism.pdf](http://wiki.edg.com/twiki/pub/PublicRepository/SG1Docs2012/TLS_and_Parallelism.pdf)

**Edit**: It's also worth pointing out that makecontext/swapcontext have been removed from The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7 as they have been marked obsolescent for some time. As an alternative, [Boost.Context](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/overview.html) has recently been added to the Boost libraries (although it doesn't support fiber-local storage either).

Comment: Thanks, I verified TLS is not affected by context change on linux.  So my further question is, is there any fiber-local-storage in linux?